# Annotations based Endpoints/Routes in Vert.x

Tags: spring-boot, jersey, resteasy, vert.x

Vert.x does have an [integration](https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-examples/tree/master/spring-examples/springboot-example) with Springboot , with Vert.x embedded in a Springboot application. Does that mean I can use Springboot annotations based approach to define Routes in Vert.x, while getting all the benefits of Vert.x reactive nature.
Vert.x also has an integration with Jersey and RestEasy, which seem to provide annotation based endpoint definitions in Vert.x. But does this approach have any impact on Vert.x application performance and responsiveness.